# Opening a file in Python

Tags: python, list, file, integer

Question:

How can I  open a file in python that contains one integer value per line. Make python read the file, store data in a list and then print the list?

I have to ask the user for a file name and then do everything above. The file entered by the user will be used as 'alist' in the function below.

Thanks

```
def selectionSort(alist):
    for index in range(0, len(alist)):
        ismall = index
        for i in range(index,len(alist)):
            if alist[ismall] > alist[i]:
                ismall = i
        alist[index], alist[ismall] = alist[ismall], alist[index]
    return alist
```

Comment: have you actually tried to do it? if so, post your code.

Comment: please also supply sample inputs and outputs

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you need:

```
file = open('filename.txt', 'r')
lines = [int(line.strip()) for line in file.readlines()]
print(lines)
```

I didn't use a `with` statement here, as I was not sure whether or not you intended to use the file further in your code.

---

**EDIT**: You can just assign an input to a variable...

```
filename = input('Enter file path: ')
```

And then the above stuff, except open the file using that variable as a parameter...

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
```

Finally, submit the list `lines` to your function, `selectionSort`.

```
selectionSort(lines)
```

*Note*: This will only work if the file already exists, but I am sure that is what you meant as there would be no point in creating a new one as it would be empty. Also, if the file specified is not in the current working directory you would need to specify the full path- not just the filename.

Comment: And how could I prompt the user to enter a file name and then do all the stuff above?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to open a file in Python and store its contents in a string:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  contents = f.read()
```

for your problem:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  values = [int(line) for line in f.readlines()]
print values
```

Edit: As noted in one of the other answers, the variable `f` only exists within the indented `with`-block. This construction automatically handles file closing in some error cases, which you would have to do with a `finally`-construct otherwise.

Comment: This will only work if OP is using Python 2 due to the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the list of integers to a string or a list

```
file = open('file.txt', mode = 'r')
values = file.read()
```

values will have a string which can be printed directly

```
file = open('file.txt', mode = 'r')
values = file.readlines()
```

values will have a list for each integer but can't be printed directly

Answer (score 0):

`f.readlines()` read all the lines in your file, but what if your file *contains a lot of lines*?

You can try this instead:

```
new_list = [] ## start a list variable

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ## remove '\n' from the end of the line
        line = line.strip()

        ## store each line as an integer in the list variable
        new_list.append(int(line)) 

print new_list
```